# TableView заполняется(судя по всему), но поля остаются невидимыми

Tags: java, javafx

Есть база данных с табличкой "Блюда" (dishes). Хочу отобразить ее в TableView.
Вроде все делаю правильно, в коллекцию блюда заносятся. Но в итоге смотрю на таблицу, а элементов нет. Но самое странное, что я в таблице могу выбрать ровно то количество элементов, которые сейчас есть в базе(проверял с разным количеством). То есть такое ощущение, будто элементы все-же есть а отобразить их не могу. И да,в классе Dishes все поля SimpleIntegerProperty или SimpleStringProperty

```
@FXML
    void initialize() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        // Беру из базы блюда
        ObservableList<Dishes> DishesList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Config config = new Config();
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        PreparedStatement prSt = config.getDbConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM dishes");
        resultSet = prSt.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()){
            int IdIDish = resultSet.getInt(1);
            String DishName = resultSet.getString(2);
            String DishType = resultSet.getString(3);
            int DishPrice = resultSet.getInt(4);
            int IdIDiet = resultSet.getInt(5);
            DishesList.add(new Dishes(IdIDish, DishName, DishType, DishPrice, IdIDiet));
        }

        //Настраиваю столбцы
        DishTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        IdDish.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("IdDish"));
        DishName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("DishName"));
        DishType.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("DishType"));
        DishPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("DishPrice"));
        IdDiet.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("IdDiet"));

        //Заполняю таблицу
        DishTable.setItems(DishesList);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ЖекаДиулин это десктопное приложение, откуда в нем взяться браузерным инструментам разработчика?)

Comment: @Ilya, добавьте в вопрос описание класса Dishes

Comment: Ой, я что-то попутал, простите)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для использования TableView с Object, **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО** должны быть использованы геттеры и сеттеры, для полей вашего класса Object. Если в вашем классе их нет, то будут пустые ячейки.

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае `PropertyValueFactory` не то что нужно.

Нужно создать свою фабрику, которая будет возвращать `SimpleStringProperty` или `SimpleIntegerProperty`.

Вот пример который будет работать:

```
public class DishNameTableCellValueFactory<Dishes> implements Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Dishes, String>, ObservableValue<String>> {

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Dishes, String> param) {
        return param.getValue().getDishName();
    }

}
```

Использование:

```
DishName.setCellValueFactory(new DishNameTableCellValueFactory());
```

Answer (score 0):

Все, что в методе Initialize - правильно. Но нужно было в классе Dishes создать геттеры для всех полей. Хотя они конкретно у меня и не используются, но видимо, программа, автоматически к ним обращается для работы с этим классом.